# IE 8 footer won't go full-width with Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

I tried every solutions but I can't seem to expand the footer beyond 1200px unlike the header and timeline.

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 which isn't IE8 friendly but I'm using the REM Javascript and Conditional tags to make it work well on IE8.

Here's my CSS:

```css
.footer-block{
  background: #8f77b3;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%
}

.footer-text{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-text b{
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

And my HTML

```html
<!-- Footer Section -->
<section class="footer-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns"><p class="footer-text">For more information please visit: <b>www.experian.co.uk/debt-map</b></p></div>
  </div>
</section><!-- End of Footer -->
```

Additionally, you may view the whole website: **http://www.planet.nu/dev/debt-burden-responsive/map.html**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time pinpointing the problem but I have a clue:

When I inspect the CSS for **.footer-block .row**, the CSS on all browsers but IE8 call **.row**.

When I inspect in IE8, it calls **.row .row**. That selector uses different sets of rules and negative margins to line things up correctly. You might want to check your HTML and see if you missed a closing tag. You could also do a specific rule for IE8 on **.footer-block .row**.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I wasn't able to write another </div> before the end of the section. It works perfectly well now.